# UDP socket still bound to previous port – how to reuse it?

Tags: sockets, boost, udp, port

I have an audio streaming application that uses boost UDP sockets bound to port 50050. I currently have a problem when the application is shut down while streaming. When restarting the app it cannot bind to port 50050 anymore.
I did a "netstat -p UDP" and it shows me the following

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address (state)

udp4 1026 0 *.50050 *.*

So, basically the receive queue for this socket is not empty and the previously bound port is indeed still active.

Now I wonder if a) there is way to force binding to port 50050 or b) the socket receive queue can be cleared or c) the existing socket could be reused or d) if you have other suggestions how to solve the issue ?

Thanks in advance,
best

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike with TCP an UDP socket is not lingering around in some temporary state once the socket is closed by the application. What you see means therefore that there is still a process owning a socket bound to this port. This suggest that the application was not fully shutdown but at least one thread of it is still running. Or it might be a forked child which inherited the socket.

While you can create an additional socket with SO_REUSEADDR (see other comments and answers for details) this will not make the already existing socket inactive. Data send to this port will end up at only one of the existing sockets and will not be propagated to all. This might lead to data loss.

Comment: This is indeed what I had in mind, too, however, there is no such process running anymore. I checked it via ps aux and top but did not discover any "leftovers". Is there anything I might be missing though ?

Comment: @AlexanderCarôt: Not sure which platform you are on, but in Linux you can do `netstat -p -u` to find out the process for the socket.

Comment: I am deploying for Linux, OSX and Windows, however, I discovered the issue on OSX where netstat cannot show the PID. There I used lsof -i -n -P | grep 50050 which did the job eventually – results in next message.

Comment: Besides the pure audio streaming I perform a traceroute for statistical reasons. The call is set by my C++ app via fp = popen(exec.c_str(), "r"); where exec contains the console based traceroute call and this one is still in action after the main app has shut down. Thanks a lot for your help – now it's up to me to fix this issue !

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I now run traceroute with the following parameters: traceroute -I -w 1 -m 15 so it uses ICMP instead of UDP (less rejected connections), sets 1 s instead of 3 s timout and limits the maximum amount of hops to 15 instead of 20.

Answer (score 1):

Set the SO_REUSEADDR property on the socket before invoking `bind`.

```
int fAllow = 1;
int result;


result = ::setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &fAllow, sizeof(fAllow));
```

Comment: While this is technically correct it does not solve the problem that there is still a socket out there bound to the same port. Any data send to this port will end up only at one of these sockets, not both.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I agree - assuming the rogue process holding onto the socket is still calling `recvrom` or equivalent reading operation. OP needs to find out what process is still holding onto his socket.  He didn't say which OS, but there are command line options for `netstat` to reveal the process that is holding onto a port/socket.

Comment: See above – eventually I could figure what the issue was and indeed there was still a side process running which was the main reason. However, your answer was still useful because I explicitly asked how to reuse the port. Thanks !